GeoServer: permission only to gwc?
Is it possible to setup the GeoServer that a normal user of the GeoServer could only see/control the tile-caching part of GeoServer?
like in 1


You could just install gwc if that is all you need

no, i want the whole geoserver and not just the gwc. Actually there is a whole geonode running, too and every user of a geonode-specific group of the geonode should be able to pre-render layers. Thought it would be good idea to break down the complete probleme into small simple pieces ;)

Set your webserver to only forward connections to gwc
